# Request Two Models together

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models that are many to many. They're used on the first page of my app and I'm having trouble loading them.

Both models only have a handful of items (<200) and I'd like to just load both models completely in one `findAll` request each.  But as the first model gets loaded, Ember starts fetching the missing data for the second model, item by item.  If I try to just load the models separately, I get an error and have to set `{async:true}` for the `hasMany` attr.  For some reason though, Ember isn't recognizing the json of the requests for the second model.

Is there anyway to fetch both models and wait till the both load before continuing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm guessing you are doing something along the lines of:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // Fetch the records of the first model 
    return this.store.find('post');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.store.find('comment').then(function(comments) {
      controller.set('comments', comments)
    });
  }
});
```

Any promise returned from the `model` hook of the route, will cause the router to pause transitioning until that promise is fulfilled. In the above case, the router will wait **only** for the `posts` request to resolve. Therefore we need to instruct the router to wait for both requests to complete.

Enter [`Ember.RSVP.all`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md#arrays-of-promises) and [`Ember.RSVP.hash`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md#hash-of-promises). These methods allow for merging multiple promises into one. They return a new promise that is fulfilled only when all of the individual promises are fulfilled. Here is how you do it with `Ember.RSVP.hash`:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var store = this.store;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      posts: store.find('post'),
      comments: store.find('comment')
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, models) {
    var posts = models.posts;
    var comments = models.comments;

    controller.set('content', posts);
    controller.set('comments', comments);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That works great!!  Sorry for not providing a code example.  I'm actually using the models in two different render helpers, each with their own controller.  For some reason, when it gets to those controllers, it's running the promise again?  I thought that part of Ember-data is that it loads cache data?  Should I be doing something differently?

Comment: How does this work in the case of `#link-to`, where the `model` hook isn't called?

Comment: And this would not fly for models based on query params because refreshModel: true doesn't call the setupController hook. I also can't seem to figure out how to get params in the setupController method.

Comment: you wouldn't need to call setupController if you access posts and comments through model: model.posts and model.comments.