# Multiple models to Ember route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of printers

```
GradingX.PrintersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var printerList = Em.A();

        //Ember.
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/printers").then(function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                printerList.addObject(item);
            }), function () {
                alert("$.getJSON failed!");
            };
        });
        return printerList;
    },
});
```

That I'm trying to access from my header

```
GradingX.HeaderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        //console.log("test in header model route");
        //return Ember.Object.create({
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            printers: What Goes Here?,
            otherObjects: More Stuff Here
        });
    },
});
```

I'm trying to follow the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523510/697827, but since I'm not accessing through Ember-Data I don't think this.store.find('printers') is going to get me what I need.

I'm missing something. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`RSVP.hash` expects an object with keys and promises as values. So I think that the following could work:

```
GradingX.HeaderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            printers: $.getJSON("http://localhost/printers"),
            otherObjects: $.getJSON("http://localhost/???")
        });
    },
});
```

In the referenced answer is used `this.store.find`, which also returns a promise, but it's resolved with a `DS.RecordArray` (an array like object provided by ember data). So what matters for `RSVP.hash` are promises.

Comment: I gave that a try and I'm not seeing the request getting sent out

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your localhost doesn't have a port, are you using the port 80?

Comment: oh sorry i abstracted away the port #. it exists in my code