# Ember.js: How do I associate my component with a model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js and am trying to figure out how to piece things together at this point. One component I built, since I need a re-usable "widget" to use across many portions of my application, is a "site nav" widget. Basically, it's almost like the buttons/links you see in StackOverflow when you open a new question titled: "Questions Tags Users Badges Unanswered". In my app, these links have a name and id associated with them on the server-side. I want to be able to use this navigation widget on multiple parts of my app and it should be as simple as putting:

`{{site-nav}}`

into a template. I got that part working just fine, but the navigation is currently hard coded in handlebars. My question is, for a component, where is the right place to retrieve/populate model data from the server? For a controller, we do it directly from the controller's route definition. The component is not associated with a router. In fact, it can be re-used, as mentioned before, in several parts of the app.

I want to be able to drop this component into templates and have it populated with modeled nav from the server which has the name/IDs of the navigation I need. Where is the best place to do this? I'm guessing I'll still extend from something like `DS.Model`, but I'm not entirely sure where/when/how to integrate this with the component. When do I create the model and invoke a `.find()` type call to the server to populate `site-nav` with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass value to component [Passing properties to component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/)
via handlebars.

```
{{my-nav navlist=listfromserver}}
```

so the list from server is in our controller can be passed to the component

Comment: But the controller is associated with a different `model`. Are you saying there's a way to have it associated with both the `site navigation` AND its own respective modeled data?

Comment: you can get data from the that controller which has this data using controller dependencies. using needs : ['controller with navlist'] in current controller  can you make a jsbin it will be easier for me to understand

Comment: Not sure I'm getting this. Components aren't associated with any particular controller as far as I'm aware. That means using `needs` only makes sense if I need data from another controller. I'm just trying to make a re-usable component that has its own associated data.

Comment: there are multiple approaches. You can associate multiple models to one controller too. depends how your app is. you can check this out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models

Comment: well I too am learning ember  and for components it written in docs " There is no access to the surrounding context or outer controller; all contextual information must be passed in." if a component has a controller and route how will it be different from normal view/template

Comment: Hi if you think my answer is valid please make it accepted unless you wating for better answer.