# `needs` not waiting for data to be returned before rendering template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to implement a controller [needing](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) another (`CampaignsNew` needing `AppsIndex`), which looks like

```
App.CampaignsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs: ['appsIndex']
});
```

And in my `CampaignsNew` template I am showing it via

```
{{#if controllers.appsIndex.content.isUpdating}}
  {{view App.SpinnerView}}
{{else}}
  {{#each controllers.appsIndex.content}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

However `controllers.appsIndex.content.isUpdating` is never true. I.e. it attempts to show the data before it has been loaded.

My `AppsIndex` route has the model overridden:

```
App.AppsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(controller) {
    var store = this.get('store').findAll('app');
  }
  ...
});
```

I can get it to work if I put the same code within my `CampaignsNew` route and modify the template to `each` through `controller.content`. Which says to me that `needs` is not using the route? It also works if I go to the `/apps` page and it loads the data, and then navigate to the `/campaigns/new` page.

How do I get this to work? Thanks!

**Edit:** 
As requested, the relevant parts of my router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('apps', function() {
    ...
  });

  this.resource('campaigns', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

And the `AppsIndex` is accessed at `/apps` and `CampaignsNew` is at `/campaigns/new`

**Edit2:**
After implementing the suggestion by @kingpin2k, I've found that Ember is throwing an error. Below are the updated files and the error received.

```
App.CampaignsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  pageTitle: 'New Campaign'
});

App.CampaignsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(controller) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      campaign: this.store.createRecord('campaign'),
      apps: this.store.find('app')
    });
    // return this.store.createRecord('campaign');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('apps', model.apps);
    this._super(controller, model.campaign);
  }
});
```

Ember throws this error:

```
Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('apps', <DS.RecordArray:ember689>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.CampaignsNewController:ember756>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

I [read online](http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/01/27/controller-objectcontroller-and-objectproxy/) that this is because the content object doesn't exist. If I set it like so:

```
App.CampaignsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: Ember.Object.create(),
  ...
});
```

Then the page loads without error, and when inspecting the Ember Chrome extension, I can see the data has loaded. But it doesn't show on the page. Which I suppose happened because the `content` object existed and so Ember didn't wait for the model's promise to fulfill before rendering the template. Seems odd that you should have to define content in such a way though. Any insight on how to handle this?

**Edit3:** Question answered for me in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618210/creating-a-new-record-not-pulling-data-from-template-fields)

Comment: will you show your router?  and mention which route you're actually hitting `foo/bar/1`

Comment: I've edited and added above, @kingpin2k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your router, `apps` isn't a parent of `campaigns/new`.

This means someone could hit `#/campaigns/new` and Ember would hit `ApplicationRoute`, `CampaignsRoute`, and `CampaignsNewRoute` to populate the necessary information for the url requested.  Using needs as a way of communicating between controllers really only makes sense in an ancestral pattern (aka communicating with your parents, grandparents etc).

Just as another quick note, `AppsIndex` is a route of `Apps`, it won't be hit when your url includes a child.  e.g.

#### Router

```
this.resource('apps', function() {
  this.resource('chocolate', function(){
     .....
  });
});
```

#### Url being hit

```
#/apps/chocolate
```

#### Routes that will be hit

```
ApplicationRoute
AppsRoute
ChocolateRoute
ChocolateIndexRoute
```

The index route is only hit when you don't specify a route of a resource, and you are hitting that exact resource (aka nothing past that resource).

### Update

You can return multiple models from a particular hook:

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      cows: this.store.find('cows'),
      dogs: this.store.find('dogs')
    });
  }
});
```

If you want the main model to still be cows, you could switch this up at the `setupController` level.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      cows: this.store.find('cows'),
      dogs: this.store.find('dogs')
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('dogs', model.dogs);  // there is a property on the controller called dogs with the dogs
    this._super(controller, model.cows);  // the model backing the controller is cows
  }
});
```

Check out the second answer here, [EmberJS: How to load multiple models on the same route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models/20523407#20523407) (the first is correct as well, just doesn't mention the gotchas of returning multiple models from the model hook).

You can also just set the property during the `setupController`, though this means it won't be available when the page has loaded, but asynchronously later.

### Which controller?

Use Controller if you aren't going to back your controller with a model.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

Use ObjectController, if you are going to set the model of the controller as something, that isn't a collection.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      cows: this.store.find('cows'),
      dogs: this.store.find('dogs')
    });
  }
});
```

Use ArrayController if that something is going to be a collection of some sort.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
    return ['asdf','fdsasfd'];
  }
});
```

#### Note

If you override the setupController, it won't set the model of the controller unless you explicitly tell it to, or use `this._super`.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){  
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      cows: this.store.find('cows'),
      dogs: this.store.find('dogs')
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('cows', model.cows);
    controller.set('dogs', model.dogs);
    // uh oh, model isn't set on the controller, it should just be Controller
    // or you should define one of them as the model
    // controller.set('model', model.cows); or
    // this._super(controller, model.cows); this does the default setupController method
    // in this particular case, ArrayController
  }
});
```

Comment: Really insightful, thank you! I need to be able to display the `apps`, but don't want to replace the `CampaignsNew` model with `this.get('store').findAll('app')` as then I can't pull in a new record for Campaign. Essentially I'm creating a `Campaign` and it will have an `App` that will belong to it, and I want them to be able to select it. Do you have a suggestion as to how I could achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed, well-formatted answer.

Comment: Side question: should I be using `ObjectController` `ArrayController` or just `Controller` when returning a hash like above? Using anything but plain `Controller` results in errors attempting to delegate set to the 'content' property of object proxy whilst it's undefined. @kingpin2k

Comment: I tossed up some examples of when to use each

Comment: Thank you - I think you mistakenly used the same example for both Object and Array controller? I am indeed implementing `setupController` as you've stated. Your answer seems to imply that I shouldn't be using `Controller` but instead `ObjectController` as I am setting the model as `this.store.createRecord('campaign')` and `apps` as the returned array. However Ember throws the error `attempting to set the content property of object proxy whilst it's undefined`. Thank you again @kingpin2k you've been more than helpful.

Comment: hah, yes, I totally did, and I saw it and told myself I was going to fix it, then forgot.  Will you show me in your question?

Comment: I found your other question, I'm still editing it up a bit, but it's close to done.