# Best spot to pull in reference data for a route

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that requires extra reference data as well as the regular model for drop downs and alike.  Where is the best place to put this?  I was thinking that maybe the afterModel hook but I am not sure.

```
afterModel : function(site, transition) {
    this.store.find('stuff', {site : site.get('id')});
    this.store.find('moreStuff');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the `setupController` hook is the appropriate place to do this, since you'll generally be attaching this reference data to the controller for use there.  Although, you can block the transition by returning a promise to the `afterModel` hook, if you need this data to be available before the controller is set up, though you'll need to keep track of the values in the route, then manually assign them in `setupController`.

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set('stuff', this.store.find('stuff', {site : site.get('id')}));
}
```

or if you use `afterModel`

```
afterModel : function(site, transition) {
   var self = this,
       store = this.store;
   return Em.RSVP.hash({
     stuff: store.find('stuff', {site : site.get('id')}),
     more: store.find('moreStuff')
   }).then(function(hash){
     self.set('extraCrap', hash);
   });
},

setupController: function(controller, model){
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set('stuff', this.get('extraCrap.stuff'));
}
```

You can also look at this, but be sure to read the second answer: [EmberJS: How to load multiple models on the same route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models/20523407#20523407)

Answer (score 0):

What I find the best approach and i'm also using for these exact cases is the `hash` function of Ember.RSVP within the route's `model` function.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.html#method_hash

This way the route is only loaded when all required resources are available. It is also handy to take advantage of the `loading` substate (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

Usually I also proxy the calls from a specific controller's functions that handles caching, as lookup values hardly change within a session. The functions return the promise directly if the requested lookup values are not found in cache.

The other option, if needed to avoid `Ember.RSVP` would probably be in `setupController` or `afterModel` functions but would have to take care of displaying a modal loading spinner until loading had been completed.