# Ember - specify controller for named outlet

Tags: ember.js

I have a template called new, which has some input helpers to submit a new Request (subject and body). After them I have a named outlet tags, which should display a list of possible services we can add to the request (tags: fix, purchase, etc).

The problem is that when I navigate to new, only static data is displayed from the tags template ("inside tags template" would be displayed), but the #each does not loop at all.

If I add tags as a new resource into new, and navigate to new/tags, then the tags template would be rendered into both outlets of the new template ({{outlet}} and {{outlet tags}}, so my code is not faulty when it comes to displaying data, its just faulty when it comes to displaying it where and when I want to (only inside the new route).

Also, both my routes' models have a console.log message saying which route is accessed, and when I go to new only the new route displays a message.

I believe new does not know that it is supposed to use the tags controller, but I am clueless when it comes to Ember... (I do not want to get the tags via the new route, I want to use the tag route)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    console.log("in new");
},
setupController : function(controller, model){
    controller.set("model", model);
},

renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();
    this.render('tags', {
        outlet: 'tagO',
        into: "new",
        controller: 'tags'
    });

}
```

});

Comment: The example in the code block before the last code block in [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) uses `controllerFor` to get the reference of the controller. Have you tried that? Also, just in case, try also `requests/tags` if your controller is in nested folders.

Comment: Both files are in the same folder, and I already tried controllerFor...

Comment: i think you're passing the wrong parameter to `into`.. You're passing the same template you're trying to insert into... I *think* it should be the name of the template where the outlet `tagO` is defined, which I suspect it would be `request`?

Comment: no, there are just the new and tags templates, tags should be rendered into new's {{outlet tag0}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to just type `{{render  'tags' someModel}}` from the template than to programmatically do it in the `renderTemplate` hook and named outlet.  You need to make the `someModel` available on the controller that you are currently in.

You'll want to hook up multiple models on the controller, see: [EmberJS: How to load multiple models on the same route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route/20523407#20523407)

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1051/edit