# Can't find the right name for a computed alias in EmberJS with Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-cli for an emberjs project. I want a property on my controller to be an alias for a property on my route. I can't find the right way to set it up, and the property is always undefined.

Here's my router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('surveys', function() {
    this.route('editCompletedSurvey', { path: '/:survey_id/:completed_survey_id' });   
  });
});
```

And `routes/surveys/edit-completed-survey.js`:

```
import NewCompletedSurvey from 'myapp/routes/surveys/new-completed-survey';

export default NewCompletedSurvey.extend({
  completedSurveyId: null,

  model: function(params) {
    this.set('completedSurveyId', params.completed_survey_id);
    console.log('Set completedSurveyId to ' + params.completed_survey_id);    // gets set correctly
    return this.store.find('survey', params.survey_id);
  }
});
```

And finally my controller:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  completedSurveyId: Ember.computed.alias('SurveysEditCompletedSurveyRoute.completedSurveyId'),    // always 'undefined'. What should this be?
  ...
```

Can anyone tell me what the value of the string passed to `alias` should be?

The reason I'm doing this is that in my controller I need to access the value of the `:completed_survey_id` parameter. I can't use `setupController` because that is only called once when the route is first accessed, and I need the controller to be able to access this parameter's value as the user selects different surveys to view. If there's a better way to do that, please tell me (note: `completed_survey_id` isn't the ID of a `survey` model instance, but is an ID of a different model).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you want to have the property on the `Route` but Ember does not (easily) give you access to the route from the controller. `Route`s can acces `Controller`s but there is no default way to go the other way around.

Comment: I know *what* I want to do, but this is my first ember project so I don't entirely know *how* to do it. All I need is to get access to a route parameter from the controller so I can load a different model and merge them together into the output. I can't see any way to get hold of the route parameters in the controller directly, so I thought creating a property on the route would work.

Comment: If you need to load a different model then you should transition to the route passing the new model id and let the router fetch the new model and pass it to the controller

Comment: I need to merge the values of two models into the same output template, not view a different model on its own. The other model doesn't have a route because it doesn't make sense to view it on its own.

Comment: if the other model is not based off the route, then in the route how do you know which other model to load?

Comment: See the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route/20523407#20523407, setupController is hit each time the model changes, not just the first time.

Comment: @Kingpin2k OK thanks, that looks like what I need. I'll try again with setupController.

Comment: You may also want to think of using another deeper nested resource, if you want the url to be changing with your id.  It sounds like you want a master detail view

Comment: TBH I'm inheriting where I should be composing, but one step at a time.