# Add second model to a route

Tags: ember.js, relationship, has-many, relationships

My application is for swimming lessons. I need to add swimmers to a class. The relationship is has many in  both directions. A Lesson can have many Swimmers and Swimmers can have many Lessons.

From the lesson route, I would like to select a swimmer in a drop down, from a list of all swimmers and have an action add that swimmer's ID to the lesson's "swimmers" array.

I can't get the swimmers to show up in the drop down field because I don't think I am loading the second model correctly.

I would also be open to suggestions of how to add a specific swimmer to a specific class. It's important to see all available swimmers

I am new to both ember and programming so please keep this in mind when making suggestions. Thank you!

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('lessons', { path: '/lessons' }, function() {
  this.resource('lesson', { path: '/:lesson_id' })
  this.route('new', { path: '/new' })
});

this.resource('swimmers', { path: '/swimmers' }, function() {
  this.resource('swimmer', { path: '/:swimmer_id' })
  this.route('new', { path: '/new' })
});

});


App.Lesson = DS.Model.extend({

type: DS.attr(),
name: DS.attr(),
/*level: DS.attr(),   sometimes there are hybrid levels, likely leave it up to */
instructor:DS.belongsTo('instructor', {async: true}),
startDate: DS.attr(),
endDate: DS.attr(),
capacity: DS.attr('number'),
swimmers: DS.hasMany('swimmer',{async: true}),
});

App.Swimmer = DS.Model.extend({


  nameFirst: DS.attr(),
  nameLast: DS.attr(),
  level: DS.attr(),
  birthdate: DS.attr(),
  gender: DS.attr(),
  note:DS.attr(),
  lessons: DS.hasMany('lesson', {async: true}),
  });



 App.LessonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          lesson: this.store.find('lesson', params.lesson_id),
          swimmers: this.store.findAll('swimmer')
      })
   },

   setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.lesson);
    controller.set('swimmer', model.swimmer);
  },
});
```

Drop down I am trying to use

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="lesson_swimmers" class="col-sm-2 control-     label">Swimmers</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        {{view Ember.Select content=swimmers optionLabelPath="content.fullName" class="form-control" id="lesson_swimmers"}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try to rename variables: `controller.set('swimmer', model.swimmer);` -> `controller.set('swimmers', model.swimmers);` to match model's properties in `App.LessonRoute.model` hook and `App.LessonRoute.setupController` hook.

Comment: I tried that, but now I get the following error,  `Error while processing route: lesson Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('swimmers', ) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.LessonController:ember752>: its 'content' is undefined. Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('swimmers', ) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.LessonController:ember752>: its 'content' is undefined.`

Comment: You need to add 'swimmers' property to App.LessonController (`swimmers: null`)

Comment: Thanks @Microfed. That sort of worked, but the data only loads when I access the page via direct url. If it is accessed through a link-to the swimmers do not load on the page, but they are showing up in the ember data inspector.

Comment: That's because you don't load all required model when transitioning to `App.LessonRoute`. Check this answer, please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523407/614425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to this question. The right one for you will depend on how you are providing the Model.

If you are arriving via **transferTo** or **linkTo** you will need to use a different approach than if you are arriving directly via URL.

@Kingpin2k answers the question and provides examples here,

[Kingpin2k's elegant solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523407/)