# Ember access data of another controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The Trucks model is backed by a db, and accessible via a rest api.
The Analysis model, however, is NOT backed by a db but is simply used for computations on the client side.

I need to access the Trucks array from within the Analyses controller, but I encounter 2 problems

1. Trucks data needs to be retrieved from the database. If I visit the `/analyses` route immediately then there are no Trucks in the data store when checking the ember console. However, if I visit `/trucks` first then I notice 6 records are retrieved and in the data store.
2. Inside the `AnalysesController` I have specified the dependency on Trucks but I am unable to access the data from within the controller. http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/  shows how to access from within a template.

Below is the code

```
// router.js
Classmove.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('trucks');
  return this.resource('analyses');
});

Classmove.TrucksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('truck');
  }
});

Classmove.Analyses = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('analysis');
  }
});



// analyses_controller.js
Classmove.AnalysesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['trucks'],
  trucks: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.trucks'),
  isCalculating: false,
  checkTrucks: function() {
    // I want to access the trucks here
    // I found that I was able to access it like so
    this.get('trucks').model.content 
    // but shouldn't there be a direct way without bypassing Ember
  },
  actions: {
    calculate: function() {
      // does stuff - removed from example for simplicity
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use get method to access properties. Instead of `this.get('trucks').model.content` use `this.get('trucks.model')` and do not forget about `observes('trucks.model)` on `checkTrucks` method

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer to be helpful [EmberJS: How to load multiple models on the same route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route/20523407#20523407)

The router waits for promises to complete on the `beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel` hooks.

In my example, the `afterModel` hook returns a hash of promises. When the promises are fulfilled it set the `trucks` and `locations` attributes on the `AnalyzeRoute`. Once the promises have completed, `setupController` hook is called where we read the attribute from the `AnalyzeRoute` and set them on the controller.

I'm not reading the data from another controller. I'm reading the data from the store because the `TrucksController` may not have been visited before the `/analyze` route is called hence it's model attribute may not have been set.

```
// router.js.coffee
App.AnalyzeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.all('location-analysis') # don't fetch from server, checks local store
  afterModel: ->
    Ember.RSVP.hash
      trucks: @store.find('truck').then (trucks) => @set('trucks', trucks)
      locations: @store.find('location').then (locations) => @set('locations', locations)
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    this._super(controller, model)
    controller.set 'trucks', @get('trucks')
    controller.set 'locations', @get('locations')



// analyze_controller.js
App.AnalyzeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  checkTrucks: ->
    trucks = @get('trucks') # returns an Ember Record Array
    # do some checking
  actions:
    calculate: ->
      // does stuff - removed from example for simplicity
```