# Nested routes and array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my app I have the following setup:

**Router**

```
this.resource('types');
this.resource('type', {path: 'types/:type_id'})
```

When a user navigates to `types` he gets a list with all the different types. When he clicks on a link he navigates to the specific type:page. Here I would like to show an array of products. Each type has an array of products. I tried to get the products doing so:

```
this.resource('types');
this.resource('type', {path: 'types/:type_id'}, function(){
    this.resource('products', {path: '/products'});
});
```

**Router**

```
model: function(){
    return this.store.find('product');
}
```

but that didn't work. I also tried with the params but that doesn't work.

```
model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('product', {id: params_id});
}
```

**Templates**

Type-template

```
  <h3>{{name}}</h3>
  <hr>
  {{outlet}}
```

Product-template

```
  {{#each}}
       {{name}}
  {{/each}}
```

But nothing gets loaded in the template. I don't know if this is the way to go. I had some success with removing the nested route and simply loading the two models in the `afterModel` hook on the `typeController`, but that doesn't give me access to some other models, linked to the product.

It's very frustrating that some "easy" things, like loading an array of products that belong to a type, is such a hassle.

**Edit**
What I try to achief is that when you visit the homepage you can

1. click a link "types" that takes you to the url ..../types and shows you a list of all the types. No problem there.
2. When you click on a type it takes you to types/type_id (e.g. types/1) and show you some info about the specific type (that works too).
3. On that same page I want to show a list of all the products associated with this type. Here is where I'm struggling

**Models**
type

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
products: DS.hasMany('product', {async: true})
```

product

```
name: DS.attr('string'),
prodcuts: DS.belongsTo('type', {async: true})
```

I tried this first by passing two models on the same route as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route/20523407#20523407). That works fine to some extend, but I want to put an action and computed property on each of the products and because the models are loaded in the afterModel hook, they don't get updated. I thought the way to go was to input a nested resource that returns me all of the products based on the type_id but I can't get that to work somehow.

Comment: Could you please provide the jsbin?

Comment: it is not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here?  you are saying that when you click the link from a collection of types... then each `type` has-many `product` associated with it?  do you have your models set up that way? can you show that?  and in your `type` route you want to use `...find('type', params.type_id)` to set up the "single type" route.. the products (if defined correctly) should load up with it.

Comment: Jsbin is hard because you need to work with fixture-data etc. and it doesn't really work the same way as with a http-mock server (promises etc.)