# How to count items of a parent-route-model to use it in a nested route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Ive got a structure like that

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("levels");
  this.resource("level", {path: 'levels/:level_id'}, function()  {
    this.route("play");
  });
});
```

Now, I need to use the information of the number of items (level-records) within the nested model "level/play".
My first approach was to insert into my play-controller something like this:

```
App.LevelPlayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    getLevelCount: function() {
        var allLevels = this.store.find("level");
        var levelCount = allLevels.get("length");
        return levelCount;
    }.property()
}
```

But this seems not to work. Maybe beacause of the asynchronous loading?

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `play` route? As an aside, I very much recommend Ember CLI for a new Ember application.

Comment: Well, actually I don't have one :). I never override a route for "level/play". I simply implement a controller for "play". So when writing something like this: `this.model.set('information', myValue);` it writes the value into the parent model ("level"). Btw: Thx. I will definitely use I CLI in further projects. This one is my first try with ember.js

Comment: It seems like your project is pretty new, you should consider migrating to Ember CLI even for this one. It’s the new default for Ember applications, it’s very pleasant to work with and will be better supported than the global namespace-style applications (`App.` and the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parent route’s model has already been loaded, you can just access it in the child route:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('level');
  }
});
```

Then in your controller, you can access the level as the `model` property.

Accessing the store is more of a route thing than a controller thing.

Comment: well thats true, but what if I want to access also a special model for the sub-route (here `play`)? So if I already implement something like that for the child-/sub-route like  `return this.store.find("levelplay");`? In the end I want to access both models from the sub-route-controller: The routes own model and the parent model.

Comment: You can solve that by loading multiple models in the route, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route).