# Ember - Using multiple models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a GUI for changing lots of attributes for lots of different models, from the single route.

So I've read a little about using multiple models [here].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route)

To give me the following:

```
    model: function() {

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        students: this.store.find('student'),
        objectives: this.store.find('objective')
    });
}
```

I was expecting that I could then display records etc with the following template code:

```
<h1>Objectives</h1>
{{#each objective in objectives}}
<p>{{objective.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

How should I access/display the records and their attributes in the template? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the objectives on the model:

```
<h1>Objectives</h1>
{{#each objective in model.objectives}}
<p>{{objective.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Always so obvious when you know how! Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: No necessarily obvious since previous versions of Ember would have proxied the call to the model. Glad to help.