# EmberJS How to load multiple models on the same route inside a single sorted array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to display a merged list of item from different models.

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523510/272839) that using [Ember.RSVP.hash](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#hash-of-promises) is the trick to load multiple models. It's not enough for me since I want to have all of them in a single list.

How can I merge all the model together and sort them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a `Computed.property` which monitors the models that are changing and combines them into the array you need in your `template`.

When `modelA` or `modelB` changes your computed property will update with those results.

```
myList: Ember.computed('modelA', 'modelB', function() {
    let combinedModels = [];
    this.get('modelA').forEach( item => {
        // pull out what you need from each model item
        combinedModels.push(item);
    });
    this.get('modelB').forEach( item => {
        // pull out what you need from each model item
        combinedModels.push(item);
    });
    return combinedModels;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of modelA and modelB, I write 'model.posts.[]' (call when a post if added of removed) and 'model.posts.@each.title' (call when a title is changed).