# how to pass the Ember dynamic property from beforeModel of route to template handlebar

Tags: ember.js

I want to pass a dynamic variable which is achieved from beforeModel of a route js to corresponding template's handlebar. I know that model data can be passed through model hook. However this is not model data. Also, there is no controller involved since i don't think pass variable from route to controller then template shouldn't be the easiest way.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [ember guides beforeModel hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) is appropriate for cases,

> 1) A decision can be made to redirect elsewhere without needing to resolve the model first.
>   2) Any async operations need to occur first before the model is attempted to be resolved.

so in your case, I will encourage you to do that stuff in `setupController` hook. if you still want to pass data from `beforeModel` to template then suggested solution would be, set result in route and get those values and set it in controller through `setupController` hook. Note: You will get default controller for every route.

Comment: thanks for advice. I definitely will try setupController.  However, one question: beforeModel is something that is run when route is called. will Setupcontroller (if not an action) be run when route is called?

Comment: Yes. setupController will be called after model hook.

Comment: just checked, still can't figure out how setupController can pass non-model data.

Comment: `setupController(controller,model){ this._super(...arguments); controller.set('propName',value); }` then you can use it in corresponding template

Comment: @kumkanillam is right about setupController. You can also use "multiple models" if that covers your case, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route

Answer (score 0):

This is some route data that you need in your template, that sounds like model data to me!

Also, there is always a controller involved, as one is created by the framework to be the context of the template. What this means is that the `model()` hook actually sets the `model` property of the controller, and any `{{property}}` you look up in your template is looked up in the related controller.

Pass the data along with the rest of the data in the `model()` hook.

Comment: thanks all , in my route model hook, i already used "return RSVP.hash" to return model A and B (by findAll) to template successfully. Then, after model hook, i am trying to use setupcontroller.../.../const email=user.email/ this._super(...arguments)/controller.set('email',email) ; noticed that email is just a variable of current user's email , and i try to get this email from template. After this , in template i can neither get "email" nor my model A/B.  so I don't know where is my mistake from.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Final update: I ended up using what Locks mentioned. I didn't know that in model hook's return RSVP.hash i can use more than just this.store.findAll('xxx'), i can also use yyy: this.get('zzz')..... In another word, i was wrongly thinking that only model defined by "ember g model " can be returned by RSVP.hash.  Now everything works. thanks you all for great suggestions.