# Ember.js Return promise in ApplicationRoute when setting multiple controller models

Tags: javascript, php, ember.js

I need to set multiple models of controller in the `applicationRoute` models hook:

```
model: function() {    
    this.controllerFor('markets').set('model', this.store.pushPayload('market', marketsCache)); 
    this.controllerFor('pages').set('model', this.store.pushPayload('page', pagesCache)); 
    this.controllerFor('categories').set('model', this.store.pushPayload('category', categoriesCache)); 
    this.controllerFor('employees').set('model', this.store.pushPayload('employee', employeesCache));
}
```

In my webservers index.php file I set the javascript variables `marketsCache`, `pagesCache`, `categoriesCache`, and `employeesCache`. They are retrieved from APC cache, because the API is query intensive.

As you can see, I want the app to wait for the model to fullfill. However, promises are only for AJAX requests as far as I know. So, the question is, is it possible to wrap those `controllerFor` lines in a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pushPayload` doesn't return a promise nor a model at all, but you can push the payload, then call `all` which returns all the records in the store for that type, then you can assign it to the controllers.

```
model: function() {    
    this.store.pushPayload('market', marketsCache);
    this.store.pushPayload('page', pagesCache)
    ....

    var market = this.store.all('market'),
        pages = this.store.all('page');
    ....

    this.controllerFor('markets').set('model', model.market); 
    this.controllerFor('pages').set('model', model.pages); 
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, when I do a: `this.store.find` the REST adapter gets called I think? That is really not what I want. Because the API will get another call for the model.

Comment: sorry, I just thought about that, I realized you probably didn't want to do that, you can ignore the hash and setupController and just use `all`

Comment: Hi kingpin2k, I am fiddling on my code like crazy now to try everything what pops in  my mind. But I am quit sure the `this.store.all` does not return a promise. Like stated in the docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/ I try your suggested code now!

Comment: It doesn't return a promise, but it isn't necessary, it'll return a record array.

Comment: You are very right, it works perfect! I did not know that returning an record array is enough to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with jQuery Deferred/When:

```
var market = this.store.pushPayload('market', marketsCache);
this.controllerFor('markets').set('model', market); 

var page = this.store.pushPayload('page', pagesCache);
this.controllerFor('pages').set('model', page); 

var category = this.store.pushPayload('category', categoriesCache);
this.controllerFor('categories').set('model', category); 

var employee = this.store.pushPayload('employee', employeesCache);
this.controllerFor('employees').set('model', employee);

return $.when(market, page, category, employee);
```

Docs:  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: pushPayload doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @kingpin2k indeed, I edited my code and the `$.when` did not work. I also created a version with `RSVP.hash` based on your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331835/request-two-models-together. However that did also now work because pushPayload does not return a promise.